# How to check version of flex and bison on ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04

Most Linux and BSD systems come with flex and bison as part of the base system. I want to check version currently of flex & bison on my linux system. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--version` option:

```
$ bison --version
bison (GNU Bison) 3.0.2
Geschrieben von Robert Corbett und Richard Stallman.

Copyright © 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Dies ist freie Software; die Kopierbedingungen stehen in den Quellen. Es
gibt keine Garantie; auch nicht für VERKAUFBARKEIT oder FÜR SPEZIELLE ZWECKE.


$ flex --version 
flex 2.5.39
```